# hide (:any) from url using htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter, url

I am using CodeIgniter.  I want to hide the last segment from the URL.  My URL is given below:

```
http://localhost/metropolitan/admin/home/1
```

I create this URL using "routes.php:, which looks like this:

```
$route['home/(:any)'] = 'home/content/$1';
```

Can anyone tell me how I can hide the last segment from the URL?  Is there any method using the ".htaccess" file?

Comment: I don't think you can hide. This url send and ID into your controller, so what if there's not id? By the way, you can setup by: `http://localhost/metropolitan/admin/home.html?id=1`, let's try.

Comment: i guess simple $route['home/(:any)'] = 'home/content'; do this , remove the $1